# Windows Server 2012 R2 Remote Desktop License activation under Microsoft Azure subscription

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

So this is with some of my Windows Remote Desktop License Servers, which I am using with Microsoft Azure Cloud Subscription.
The issue I am facing is related to the license expiry. A fully functional and activated 2012 Remote Desktop Session Host server displayed the following message:
"THE REMOTE SESSION WAS DISCONNECTED BECAUSE THERE ARE NO REMOTE DESKTOP LICENSE SERVERS AVAILABLE TO PROVIDE A LICENSE.PLEASE CONTACT THE WINDOWS ADMINISTRATOR"
This was a simple setup on one server with the: connection broker, Session Host and Licensing server with 2012 CAL’s installed. And though the licensing seems to be configured correctly, in server manager.
But with the CAL(client access license), every user logging on to Server, gets the error message mentioned before. For every user, I need to update the CAL license again and again, and this issue occurs every 30 or 60 days. Kindly suggest something, and feel free to ask more details on this, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: The solution is delete the following registry key: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing

Step 2: Try connecting in again.If it doesn’t work and you get the following error message: “The remote computer disconnected the session because of an error in the licensing protocol“then all you need to do is Right-Click on the Remote Desktop Connection icon and select “Run as Administrator“.

Comment: @moinka. I believe this is a temporary solution. You have to do this again after the expiration of grace period.